# Win32 Console application or CLR -->windows form application?

Tags: winapi, c++-cli, clr

I have to have a **form** as a gui,but i also need to **write using win32 API** as i need to create another process the moment the application is launched...

I created Win32 console-->empty project..then there was an option to add **windows form** as UI...Is it possible????...as i have chosen the base project to be win32 console application.

But i really need the form in the application.

Comment: The question is not very clear. What are you trying to ultimately achieve? Can't you just make your own form using the Windows API?

Comment: Changed tags from `C++` and `C` to `C++/CLI` because Windows Forms only exist on `C++/CLI`.

Answer (score 5):

C++/CLI is perfectly able to show a Windows Form in a console program, just as a windows console program is perfectly allowed to call CreateWindow. However, if you choose console as the output file mode then the console window is still going to show up to your user in addition to whatever forms you create.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the bare Windows API to create processes. See [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).